# EF Core and SqlAzureExecutionStrategy

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I've tried to have a search for anything related to a SqlAzureExecutionStrategy for EF core and came up empty handed.

Does anyone have any information around the need for setting an execution strategy when using EF Core and SQL Azure?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In EF Core it's called `SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy` as it is also useful for on-premise SQL Server if you are using memory-optimized tables for example.

It can be enabled in this way:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(
            "<connection string>",
            options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
}
```

See [Connection Resiliency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency) for more info.

Comment: How can I add circuit breaker on top of this?

Comment: You would need to derive your own implementation from SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy and call options.ExecutionStrategy(), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency

Comment: have you figured how to implement circuit breaker in EF core? link shared above to register a Custom execution strategy does not help much.